# Remove email from an Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working through a data cleansing exercise. I'm needing to remove any e-mail from a column, but retain all other text.

- It is assumed that any e-mail is any text surrounding the @ symbol contained within spaces
- The email isn't in a fixed position within the cell (and not always contained in the cell)
- Email can be the only text in a cell

Sample Data:

| Raw Data | Formatted |
| --- | --- |
| 24B Nowhere Street, Levin 5510 | 24B Nowhere Street, Levin 5510 |
| 30 Bartholomew Road, Ashtown 5510, yourmail@Yahoo.com, 021 123 4567 - James | 30 Bartholomew Road, Ashtown 5510, 021 132 4567 - James |
| test@hotmail.com, 021 987 6543, M Sinclair | 021 987 6543, M Sinclair |
| rookie@yahoo.com |  |

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILTERXML()` can give you desired output.

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(., '@'))]")),"")
```

If your version of excel support `LAMBDA()` function then you can use below function for one go.

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A2:A5,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(a," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(., '@'))]")))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. Would you know why a string like this is returning a blank result? Your formula is working for 99% of the rows 

C/- Keith & Luanne Styles, 26 Waker Street, Po Box 329, Levin 5540

Comment: @Syzmik I think that is for `&` this character.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Do I need to update something in that formula? I used your top formula (FILTERXML)

Comment: Ampersand is one of the characters that needs to be escaped before processing with `FILTERXML()` @Syzmik

Comment: @Syzmik give a try on `=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"&","#")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(., '@'))]")),"#","&"),"")`

Comment: `=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"&","&amp;"),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(.,'@'))]")),"")` will save you a `SUBSTITUTE()` @Harun24hr

Answer (score 0):

This Tutorial is also helpful,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_Ysi1SB9cY

After going through the tutorial, please read this: when you write the if condition, you can find the cells containing '@' symbol and replace them with '@' or something and then continue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if `TEXTSPLIT()` is available:

```
=LET(X,TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(X,ISERROR(FIND("@",X)),"")))
```

---

**Note:** I splitted the text on the ", " (comma-space combo)  instead to prevent possible trailing spaces. The samples show that should work fine.

Comment: I know about `TEXTSPLIT()` but unfortunately it is still not available to my excel. My account administrator has disabled insiders. Waiting for Microsoft release.